# Add data to a listview on fragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragmentactivity

I have an fragment on activity, with an listview element on it. Can't add data to listview. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    public String[] listS ={"item1","item2","item3"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        MainFragment f = new MainFragment();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragcontainer, f);
        ft.commit();    
        //here the problem occurs
        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listf);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_row,R.id.labeld, listS));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Fragment's class:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle sis){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is your `listf` element ? In `activity_main.xml` ?

Comment: No, in the fragment's layout...

Comment: use f.getView().findViewById();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a number of problems with this method, but the root of it is that the `FragmentTransaction` `replace()` method that adds the fragment that, I assume, contains the `ListView` you're trying to find is an asynchronous process. The fragment isn't added to the Activity's view hierarchy *immediately* but some time later.

If you want to add things to a `ListView` in a `Fragment`, why not do it from within the `MainFragment` subclass' `onCreateView()` method instead? That's how it's intended to work.

EDIT: A typical `onCreateView()`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
    ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listf);
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_row,R.id.labeld, listS));             
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Already tried, but I can't get reference to ListView within the MainFragment subclass

Comment: Why is that? How do you create the layout within `MainFragment` such that you are unable to get a reference to something in that layout?

Comment: When I'm trying to add "ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listf) to MainFragment, the findViewById function is stressed (I'm working in Eclipse IDE)...

Comment: I'm doing the same, but instead i get this error: "The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type MainFragment"

Comment: You're not doing the same. I'm calling `findViewById()` from the `view` variable.

Answer (score 0):

When u add code for define your class,

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle sis) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
            ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
            return view;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are asking to the activity for that ListView

"this."findViewById(...

You can ask the fragment for the view, or managing the content of the listView inside your Fragment class.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the list view in the design windows as below. I faced the exact problem and now i could able to find the view in source code.

The main issue is IDE is appending "android" infront of ID

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```